# How can I implement animate on page scroll?

Tags: vuejs2, animate.css

When a user scrolls through a webpage, how can I trigger animate css?

Is it a matter of when v-show="element" appears, trigger x?

Using Vue 2 + animate css

Answer (score 2):

I found answer from Ikbel useful

[How to display and transition when scroll position reaches element position in the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45257308/how-to-display-and-transition-when-scroll-position-reaches-element-position-in-t#45261125)

you can achive this with custom directive which adds binding inViewport for window scroll event to elements that you want to animate.

I added data-transition to html element that I want to animate

```
<div v-vpshow data-transition="flipInX"><div>
```

and changed binding like this

```
el.$onScroll = function() {
    if (binding.def.inViewport(el)) {
        el.classList.add('animated')
        el.classList.add(el.getAttribute('data-transition'))
        el.classList.remove('before-enter')
        binding.def.unbind(el, binding)
    }
}
```