# How to display and transition when scroll position reaches element position in the screen?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Suppose this is my template:

```
<template>
    <div id="Test">
        <transition name="fade">
            <div class="row" id="RowOne">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor odit qui sit?</p>
            </div>
        </transition>
        <transition name="fade">
            <div class="row" id="RowTwo">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p>
            </div>
        </transition>
        <transition name="fade">
            <div class="row" id="RowThree">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, tenetur!</p>
            </div>
        </transition>
    </div>
</template>
```

I want to display and animate `RowOne, RowTwo and RowThree` when it's in the displayed in the viewport, respectively. Like in the [Laracasts website](https://laracasts.com/), the elements appear and animate when scroll position reaches the elements offset. Is it possible using Vue.js and javascript?

Comment: Look at my answer below, it has a working snippet too.

Comment: have you seen [vue-scroll-reveal](https://github.com/tserkov/vue-scroll-reveal)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is how you can do it with a `directive`.

```
Vue.directive('vpshow', {
  inViewport (el) {
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect()
    return !(rect.bottom < 0 || rect.right < 0 || 
             rect.left > window.innerWidth ||
             rect.top > window.innerHeight)
  },

  bind(el, binding) {
    el.classList.add('before-enter')
    el.$onScroll = function() {
      if (binding.def.inViewport(el)) {
        el.classList.add('enter')
        el.classList.remove('before-enter')
        binding.def.unbind(el, binding)        
      }
    }
    document.addEventListener('scroll', el.$onScroll)
  },

  inserted(el, binding) {
    el.$onScroll()  
  },

  unbind(el, binding) {    
    document.removeEventListener('scroll', el.$onScroll)
    delete el.$onScroll
  }  
})
```

You will need to add `v-vpshow` directive to the elements you want to animate when they become visible in the viewport.

For example:

```
<div class="row" id="RowOne" v-vpshow>...</div>
```

This directive uses two classes.

1) `before-enter`: it hides the element by default and is added automatically when the directive is bound to the element.

2) `enter`: this one should contain the transition you want to apply when the element becomes visible.

`v-vpshow` will unbind itself automatically once the element has become visible (after triggering the animation) in the viewport removing any data and events listeners that were set on `bind`.

**Here is a working example.**

```js
Vue.directive('vpshow', {
  inViewport (el) {
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect()
    return !(rect.bottom < 0 || rect.right < 0 || 
             rect.left > window.innerWidth ||
             rect.top > window.innerHeight)
  },
  
  bind(el, binding) {
    el.classList.add('before-enter')
    el.$onScroll = function() {
      if (binding.def.inViewport(el)) {
        el.classList.add('enter')
        el.classList.remove('before-enter')
        binding.def.unbind(el, binding)        
      }
    }
    document.addEventListener('scroll', el.$onScroll)
  },
  
  inserted(el, binding) {
    el.$onScroll()  
  },
  
  unbind(el, binding) {    
    document.removeEventListener('scroll', el.$onScroll)
    delete el.$onScroll
  }  
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',  
})
```

```css
/* v-vpshow classes */
.before-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}

.enter {
  transition: opacity 2s ease;  
}
/* ---------------- */



.row {  
  display: flex;
  min-height: 500px;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: tahoma;
}

#RowOne {
  background-color: yellow;  
}

#RowTwo {
  background-color: #5D576B;
}

#RowThree {
  background-color: #F7567C;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <div id="Test">
        <div class="row" id="RowOne" v-vpshow>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="RowTwo" v-vpshow>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="RowThree" v-vpshow>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, tenetur!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this works. Thank you. Side question, why does `binding.inViewport(el)` does  not work, but `binding.def.inViewport(el)` works? Could you please provide me with reference for this, it will be helpfull for me?

Comment: I actually knew that we should use `binding.ref` after inspecting `binding` in the console. I found that it had a `def` object containing all the directive definition I provided. I checked the official documentation and couldn't find any information on this `def`. So I guess it's not documented.

Comment: Oh, they should have documented it. And I never tried to check that in the console. Thank you again! Now I have a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it should be.  You should just have to set the `display` property from `none` to something visible when you detect that the user has scrolled a certain distance.

Here's another question with answers that will help you implement that:
[Show div on scrollDown after 800px](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798360/show-div-on-scrolldown-after-800px)